# Create a secure unsubscribe link for emails sent with Flask

Tags: python, email, flask

I want to generate an unsubscribe link that a user can click when receiving an email to unsubscribe that address.  I don't want to just include the email in the link because a user could edit the link to unsubscribe someone else.  Most emails I see generate some sort of token and the site knows how to match the token to the user.  How can I generate such a token with Flask?

```
for email in email_lst:
      body = 'unsubscribe link with token'
      msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
      more code to send email
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flask includes the library [itsdangerous](https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com) which is used to generate tokens by securely signing serialized data.

For each email, generate a token with the email to be unsubscribed, and create an `unsubscribe` route that accepts and decodes that token to determine who to unsubscribe.

```
from itsdangerous import URLSafeSerializer, BadData

@app.route('/unsubscribe/<token>')
def unsubscribe(token):
    s = URLSafeSerializer(app.secret_key, salt='unsubscribe')

    try:
        email = s.loads(token)
    except BadData:
        # show an error
        ...

    # unsubscribe
    ...

def send_email():
    s = URLSafeSerializer(app.secret_key, salt='unsubscribe')
    token = s.dumps(user.email)
    url = url_for('unsubscribe', token=token)

    # add the url to your message
    ...
```

Since the token is signed, a user can see the data but can't change it without invalidating the token.